# How do I embed a preact app on an existing page

Tags: preact, preact-cli

I've built a simple preact app using the default setup with preact cli's `preact create`.  Building my app using `preact build`, the `build` folder contains `index.html` as an entry point/file, meaning my app is built as a stand-alone site.

What I would like to do though is embed my preact app on an existing webpage. This means that I (probably) need my built preact app to have a javascript file as an entry point that would contain something like:

```
import {render} from 'preact'
import App from './components/app'

render(<App />, document.getElementById('id-of-tag-on-an-existing-webpage'))
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use `preact-cli` to do that, not without extensive (and extremely fragile) configuration changes. Something like [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle), which is also from the Preact team, could be an option. You want a library or a widget, not an app, if you're embedding elsewhere.